# Heroku app crashes with 'libruby.so.1.9: cannot open shared object file'

Tags: ruby, heroku, nokogiri, fog

I've never had problems deploying this app but I've just pushed and now I'm getting this weird error, which is deep enough in the stack that it's not even getting sent to Airbrake. I have a feeling it might be a problem at Heroku's end, possibly relating to https://status.heroku.com/incidents/450? What do you think?

```
2012-10-14T08:40:31+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2012-10-14T08:40:31+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2012-10-14T08:40:35+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec thin start -R config.ru -e production -p 16119`
2012-10-14T08:40:38+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.5.5/lib/nokogiri.rb:27:in `require': libruby.so.1.9: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.5.5/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.so (LoadError)
2012-10-14T08:40:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.5.5/lib/nokogiri.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
2012-10-14T08:40:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/fog-1.6.0/lib/fog/core.rb:30:in `require'
2012-10-14T08:40:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/fog-1.6.0/lib/fog/core.rb:30:in `<top (required)>'
2012-10-14T08:40:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/fog-1.6.0/lib/fog.rb:1:in `require'
2012-10-14T08:40:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/fog-1.6.0/lib/fog.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2012-10-14T08:40:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
2012-10-14T08:40:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
2012-10-14T08:40:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
2012-10-14T08:40:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
2012-10-14T08:40:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
2012-10-14T08:40:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
2012-10-14T08:40:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler.rb:128:in `require'
2012-10-14T08:40:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/boot.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
2012-10-14T08:40:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:7:in `require'
2012-10-14T08:40:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:7:in `block in <main>'
2012-10-14T08:40:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2012-10-14T08:40:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2012-10-14T08:40:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:1:in `new'
2012-10-14T08:40:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:1:in `<main>'
2012-10-14T08:40:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/fog-1.6.0/lib/fog/core/parser.rb:1:in `require'
2012-10-14T08:40:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/fog-1.6.0/lib/fog/core/parser.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2012-10-14T08:40:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `eval'
2012-10-14T08:40:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:71:in `start'
2012-10-14T08:40:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/runner.rb:187:in `run_command'
2012-10-14T08:40:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/runner.rb:152:in `run!'
2012-10-14T08:40:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2012-10-14T08:40:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:23:in `load'
2012-10-14T08:40:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:23:in `<main>'
2012-10-14T08:40:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `load'
2012-10-14T08:40:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:181:in `load_rackup_config'
2012-10-14T08:40:39+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2012-10-14T08:40:39+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2012-10-14T08:40:46+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET paintafish.herokuapp.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Comment: There was some problem with the binaries of the nokogiri 1.5.5 gem related to heroku updating their ruby-1.9.3 patch level.

In the course of messing around I caused heroku to remove the installed version of nokogiri-1.5.5 and then reinstall it with native extensions at a later point. 

I did this by vendoring the nokogiri gem, commit and push (still failing), then removing the vendored gem again (forces reinstall of gem, started working).

Comment: **Can we get some votes to reopen this question please?** This was wrongly closed given it has 4 upvotes and the fact that [there is a Github gist about the same error](https://gist.github.com/3705748) which has comments from many people who are experiencing it. I just hit the same error in the same situation just over a month after the question was asked. Deleting and recreating an application is not an acceptable solution.

Comment: I am experiencing this exact problem 6 months after the Heroku incident mentioned by OP, perhaps this problem is not related to that incident? The answer to this SO might represent a workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357760/while-migrating-from-heroku-bamboo-to-cedar-stack-some-native-libraries-are-mis

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue but with kgio (2.7.4) gem. After running out of ideas, I just deleted the heroku app and recreated. The problem disappeared.