# Heroku - Ruby On rails - Error after domain change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My app had been running for over 24 hours with no problem.

I decided to try and add a custom domain to my site. I followed the instructions and then went to my godaddy panel and changed the www from @ to mysite.heroku.com

I went to sleep and when I woke up this morning I get this error

```
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.
```

If you are the application owner, check your logs for details."

After checking the logs this is what I see

```
2013-03-02T10:22:24+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-03-02T10:22:24+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-03-02T10:22:25+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=vauxden.herokuapp.com fwd="176.251.155.165" dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-03-02T10:22:26+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=vauxden.herokuapp.com fwd="176.251.155.165" dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-03-02T10:22:39+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=vauxden.herokuapp.com fwd="176.251.155.165" dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-03-02T10:22:39+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=vauxden.herokuapp.com fwd="176.251.155.165" dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

I am fairly new to ruby on rails and heroku so I have no idea how to fix this error.

I also deleted the custom domain and changed everything back to normal in my godaddy panel yet I still get this error.

I tried to push the newest version of my code and that did not make any difference.

Comment: Have you tried assessing your website via yourappname.herokuapp.com(if on the cedar stack?)

Answer (score 0):

Did you execute `heroku run rake db:migrate` after deploying your app?

Answer (score 0):

GoDaddy can be a pain in the ass, and I second what dev said above^.  It can take a day or two to load properly, so looking for the source of the problem on that end can be unreliable.

Check to make sure everythings running correctly on Heroku's side for your app.
 Heroku's Status looks OK, https://status.heroku.com/.

Your app hasn't crashed when locally testing has it?  http:// localhost:3000/whatever

Check your gems, others seem to have a similar issue. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12880632/heroku-app-crashes-with-libruby-so-1-9-cannot-open-shared-object-file)